# Criteria returning wrong values pandas behaving strangely

Tags: pandas, apply, criteria, behavior

I have been working in getting information from certain texts in a df, where are key words that need to create a new column. The criteria is behaving strangely.

Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
data = {'DESCRIPCION':['1 CONT.40    H.C.  S.W.A.L.C: 3049   BOX WITH: AVENA ORIGINAL TETRA200ML BOX X 6 UNIT AVENA CANELA  TETRA200ML BOX X 6 UNIT BABY FOOD APPLE   113GR BOX X 24 UNIT BABY FOOD PRUNE  113GR BOX X 24 UNIT BABY FOOD PEACH   113GR BOX X 24 UNIT  CARAMEL SPREAD 6X']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

This is the code I have been using:

```
def criteria2 (row):
  if row.DESCRIPCION.find ('RED BULL')>=0:
    return ("Red Bull")
  if row.DESCRIPCION.find ('RB')>=0:
    return ("Red Bull")
  else:
    return ("Otras")

frame['Brand'] = frame.apply(criteria2,axis=1)
```

The brand column is created, but if you see carefully in the text does not appear the RB combination, it appears but with a space in between R B.  How can it be worked?

Thanks.

Comment: I get "Otras" based on the data you've provided.

Comment: you want to use `numpy.where` or `numpy.select` with the `.str` accessor

Comment: Paul H I am going to try you suggestion, think it will work better.